# Android Studio Linear column

Tags: android, android-layout

The screenshot I want is as follows:

[image: Android Studio Design Screenshot]

But currently it looks like this on the phone:

[image: Phone Screenshot]

How can I make it?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/bkstr_home"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/bkst_search"
            android:hint="Ara.."
            android:id="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="330dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/message_icon"
            android:id="@+id/btn_searchx"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_search"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        
    </RelativeLayout>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you might try:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bkstr_home"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btn_searchx"
                    android:background="@drawable/bkst_search"
                    android:hint="Ara.."
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_searchx"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/message_icon"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_button"
        android:hint="Ara.."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_searchx"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_searchx"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btn_search"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"
        android:text="M"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

And example style to test: `shape_circle.xml`:

```
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid  android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>
</shape>
```

`shape_button.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="25dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
</shape>
```

If it is working for You You can set styling (colors, stroke, etc.) as You had in screenshots.